# Importing shortkeys from windows

Tags: shortcut-keys, windows-xp

I want to install Ubuntu on my parents' PC to provide them a better performance of their old PC. Is there an easy way to import all the basic shortkeys they had in windows?

Comment: A very interesting question - that would be useful. Can you describe which kinds of keys you mean? It makes a difference for an answer - you may have different kinds of keys in mind that require separate solutions. For example, kinds of keys that come to mind are: Standard Windows system keys, and changed Windows keys, in office applications: standard keys, custom keys, downloaded extra keymaps. Keys defined in extra hotkey tool, standard keys in extra window handling tool. And so on.

Comment: I meant keys like switching language, and the keys used in the terminal. Later I decided that it is too soon for them to use the terminal. I edited the basic short keys manually and printed them the list of new keys they didn't knew before (like winkey+w).
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows keymap could be part of copyright, so I wouldn't expect this to be readily available. However, in System-Settings -> Keyboard there is Shortcuts tab, which you may wanna play around with. Language input shortcuts can be edited through System-Settings -> Text Entry.

Ask your parents which shortcuts and keys they use the most, and also make necessary changes as they learn Ubuntu, because there are going to be keys users remember only when they need to use them. Most frequently used, Ctrl+C  for copying and Ctrl+V for pasting are obviously there. Windows Key + W brings up all the open menus to select from. Ctrl+Shitf+Left-Right arrow keys position a window on half the screen , just like in windows 7 . Probably good idea is to disable workspaces in System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior. New users get confused easily with this stuff (just watch some of the videos of people trying Ubuntu for first time on youtube).

Tell them simply which program is internet, which program is word processor. Keep things simple. At least in my mother's case, I just told her which program is which, had to let her play around with the laptop by herself, and she's slowly learning.